# Integer Input validation asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to validate an input from a textbox so that it is integer and in the range of 0-255. I have a small asp.net mvc4 project

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use data annotations: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Value must be set")]
[Range(0, 250, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between 0 and 250")]
public int Value{ get; set; }
```

Comment: This does not work. Type "7" and you still will see error message. There is a bug in ASP.NET MVC or jquery-validation - it convert your values to strings and compares Strings instead of Integers

Comment: Looks like the bug is in Jquery I reproduce it on:
/*! jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.0 - 2/4/2013

Answer (score 2):

For any integer number use the method below:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Value must be set")]
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between 0 and 250")]
public int Value{ get; set; `enter code here`}
```